# How do I prevent table view scrolling behind a view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

In a `TableViewController`, I have an translucent overlay view with a message. The overlay is displayed over the `TableViewController` correctly but I can still scroll the table view behind this overlay view. How can I prevent the scrolling when the overlay is on top?

I constructed my custom overlay view in my `TableViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadData(
        id,
        success: {(doc) -> () in
            let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height)

            let overlayView = EmptyCollectionView(frame : frame)
            overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.8)
            self.view.addSubview(overlayView)

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        },
        error: {..})
}
```

I tried `self.tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

Comment: hmmm something seems wrong... where are you adding `view` to the view hierarchy?

Comment: @DonMag I updated the code to reflect when i added the overlayView

Comment: We need know the relation between self.view & self.tableview

Comment: @Kamil.S - the original post states "my `TableViewController`" so, as I noted in my answer, self.view ***is*** self.tableView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK - if you are in a `UITableViewController`, `self.view` refers to the `UITableView` itself. You want to add your overlayView as a subview of the table view's superview...

Try this:

```
tableView.superview?.addSubview(overlayView)
```

You can simplify a few things as well, and you should implement sizing control to handle changes such as device rotation:

```
let overlayView = EmptyCollectionView(frame: tableView.frame)

overlayView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.8)

tableView.superview?.addSubview(overlayView)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
overlayView.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

This should prevent touches from passing through it to the table view below it.